# Other Details about Shiva's these incarnations

Tags: shiva, identification-request

In [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226413.html) from Satarudra Samhita of Shiva Purana mentiones the Mahakala, Tara, Bala, Sodasha, Bhairava, Chinnamastaka, Dhumavan, Bagalamukha, Matanga and Kamala avatars of Lord Shiva.

I know Mahakala and Bhairava, but is any scriptures mentiones about other eight incarnations? Also, the same chapter says they are explained in Upasana Khanda. But, Which scripture has Upasana Khanda?

Comment: Mantra Shastras (Agamas) describe different forms of Shiva..Sadhaka who takes respective Mantra Dikshas from Guru and and if they can get siddhi of mantra, they can get Sakshatkara of these forms..But Puranas may or may not describe some leela for all these forms.